Python subprocess.Popen with PIPE shows significant slowness
When Python subprocess.Popen is used with stdout=subprocess.PIPE, I've noticed that run time noticeably increases. I'm using mussh or ssh to get some directories of multiple hosts using multiple processes, such
processes = []
max_hosts = 15

for host in hosts:
    cmd = """ssh {} -o LogLevel=Error 'ls -ld /home/*/ 2>/dev/null | egrep SOMETEXT'""".format(host)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, Shell=True)
    print(p.stdout.read())
    processes.add(p)
    if len(processes) >= max_hosts:
        os.wait()
        processes.difference_update[p for p in processes if p.poll() is not None]

for p in processes:
    if p.poll() is None:
        p.wait()

which takes
real 0m22.965s
user 0m2.456s
sys 0m5.701s 

Then, without directing stdout to PIPE, it only takes
processes = []
max_hosts = 15

for host in hosts:
    cmd = """ssh {} -o LogLevel=Error 'ls -ld /home/*/ 2>/dev/null | egrep SOMETEXT'""".format(host)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, Shell=True)
    processes.add(p)
    if len(processes) >= max_hosts:
        os.wait()
        processes.difference_update[p for p in processes if p.poll() is not None]

for p in processes:
    if p.poll() is None:
        p.wait()

real 0m1.337s
user 0m2.621s
sys 0m6.186

Is there any other way to redirect output to PIPE and not slow down the print process?
I would like to have output and summarize hosts with ls if there was any directories matching with egrep pattern.
I've tried using check_output, call, not limiting number of processes, and etc.

Not related to performance, but there are unbalanced single quotes in your expression. And Shell=True would need to be shell=True to actually work.

Calling p.stdout.read() before looping wait()ing makes that wait basically pointless. stdout won't be closed, to allow read to return, until the process is shutting down.

...if you want to actually run multiple subprocesses in parallel in a meaningful way, use the asyncio form of the subprocess module, or spin up a separate thread to consume output from each one.

@CharlesDuffy Ah yes, Shell is not needed here but I originally had mussh which required Shell to be true. I've also tried setting bufsize to -1, and it didn't make any difference as you mentioned. So there is no other way to make it "fast" like not using pipes?

The pipes themselves aren't the problem, except insofar as you're only reading output from one of them at a time, so you're not letting your code actually do anything in parallel.

I was also thinking using separate threads, will look into that option as well. thanks @CharlesDuffy

ah okay. that makes a lot of sense that i was reading output from one process at a time.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html for the asyncio version.

...once you're using that, you can call it from https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently

Thank you for the docs and your comments!

Is """ssh {} supposed to be f"""ssh {host}?

yes :) I had to manually copy paste code here so I omitted some characters here my bad!

What you could do is start all the subprocesses in a loop that appends them to a list. Then use a second loop to read the results.

@Barmar, ...the problem with that is that the remote processes will only run in parallel until they fill the pipe buffer, then they'll block. So it would work if the output from each process is guaranteed to be short, but not otherwise.

@CharlesDuffy There's also the network buffers and TCP windows. So unless we're talking megabytes, there's lots of buffering going on.

@Barmar, ...Hm. You're putting a lot more trust in ssh being written to optimize for throughput than I usually do; I generally think of it as round-trip-heavy and generally not optimized for high-latency connections where trusting content to be buffered in-flight is helpful. I suppose one could test actual behavior readily enough with both local and remote copies of pv on a pipeline that has a ssh transport segment in the middle and a deliberately slow (or outright blocking) consumer.

@CharlesDuffy I'm not assuming anything about SSH, that's all in the OS kernel.

@Barmar, ...yes, but what the kernel provides is only relevant if the application layer protocol design permits it to be used.

@Barmar, ...I don't know the format SSH uses at other layers particularly well, but I have implemented a sftp server or few, and SFTP splits everything up into small transactions that each get individually acked.

@CharlesDuffy What I described is automatic and built into the TCP stack. The application doesn't have to request or permit it.

@Barmar, see again "small transactions that get individually acked". If the application layer does things that increase latency by not handing data off to the kernel by doing its own higher-layer flow control, then the fact that the kernel could let more data get queued up is moot.

@CharlesDuffy AFAIK, SSH is just a simple stream protocol.

SSH does its own packetization, even when it's running on top of TCP. It's not that simple.
